# keytool error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: publicKey&#39;s is not X.509, but X509

Tags: java, security

I am getting below error -

```
keytool error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: publicKey's is not X.509, but X509
```

when trying to generate the keystore with below command -

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 366 -storepass test -keypass password -dname 'cn=${env.HOSTNAME},ou=foo,o=bar,l=testCity,s=testState,c=testCoutry' -keystore
```

I am seeing this error after I upgrade my JDK to 1.7 update 40 on my Ubuntu box.

Comment: Are you sure the keytool you are using is the one from the 1.7 JDK and not from the old one?

Answer (score 0):

My team ran into the same error message after an upgrade to 1.7u45 on Windows. This error message was introduced when https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7109096 was backported to JDK 7.

The relevant part of the code change is in CertAndKeyGen.java:

```
+        // publicKey's format must be X.509 otherwise
+        // the whole CertGen part of this class is broken.
+        if (!"X.509".equalsIgnoreCase(publicKey.getFormat())) {
+            throw new IllegalArgumentException("publicKey's is not X.509, but "
+                    + publicKey.getFormat());
+        }
```

Seems that either the default publicKey format is incorrect, or the equals check should be updated to also checks for "X509".

Answer (score 0):

We run into such issues when we changed our default security provider.
See providers list in \lib\security\java.security

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but just putting it here just in case anyone else stumbles upon it. In my case the problem was being caused by the JAVA_HOME system variable was pointing to a different directory/JDK installation that was set in system Path. Unless you have dabbled with your java.security file, check your JAVA_HOME system variable, and verify that you PATH system variable is not pointing to any other JDK installation. In my case it was. When I fixed the PATH variable, the problem went away.